# Which date's? What date's? Of which date?

Tags: grammar

Let's say there are daily interest rates available for calculation but I am not sure which date's interest rates to use. What would be an appropriate question in this situation?

Of which date's interest rate should I use?
Which date's interest rate should I use?
What date's interest rate should I use?
Or better options.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The seems like a question for [Ell.SE].

Answer (score 1):

> *Of which date's interest rate should I use?

This is ungrammatical.  To begin the question with the preposition, you could say "Of which date should I use the interest rate?"  This is, however, hopelessly stuffy sounding.  Even if you *want* to sound stuffy, this is difficult to understand and should be avoided.

> Which date's interest rate should I use?

This is a reasonable choice.

> What date's interest rate should I use?

This isn't as good, but it wouldn't be surprising to hear a native speaker utter this question.

In some contexts, it might make sense to make the question longer. For example, you might ask *Which date should I use for the interest rate?*  In other contexts, you might be able to make the question shorter, as in *Which date should I use?*